What is the best method for solving this specific Simultaneous Linear Five Equations and Five Variables?
I want to know a step by step on how to solve these five equations with five variables, please!
Could someone show me a step by step solution for this specific 5 equations and 5 variables, please?
I want to learn how to do it by hand with the best method possible.
Simultaneous Linear Equations problem for Five Variables are listed below:
Equations:

Eq.1:    560V -  560W  +    0X +    0Y +    0Z    = 60
Eq.2:   -560V + 1526W  +    0X -  910Y +    0Z    = 0
Eq.3:      0V +    0W  + 2560X -  560Y +    0Z    = 0
Eq.4:      0V -  910W  -  560X + 2470Y - 1000Z    = 0
Eq.5:      0V +    0W  +    0X - 1000Y + 2120Z    = 0



Solved Values:

V = 0.22153
W = 0.11439
X = 0.01214
Y = 0.05549
Z = 0.02618


Thank you,
Five equations with five variables along with variables values

Search for "solving systems of linear equations" online.

Look up Gauss-Jordan elimination and row-reduction of matrices. That's the standard method for solving linear systems (with any number of variables and equations). A system with coefficients like these will be messy no matter how you solve it if you're doing it by hand. I doubt anyone will be willing to write up a step by step solution for you.

A $5 \times 5$ system like this one with complicated entries should be solved by a computer. I am sorry to say that you are wasting your time attempting to do it by hand. Above $3 \times 3$, resolution by hand is too time consuming (and too prone to errors!)

Here is one way to solve it, but it does need the knowledge of matrices and the use of technology (unless you know how to find the inverse of a $5\times 5$ matrix).
First we rewrite this system of equations in matrix form.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
560 & -560 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-560 & 1526 & 0 & -910 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2560 & -560 & 0\\
0 & -910 & -560 & 2470 & -1000\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1000 & 2120
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
V\\
W\\
X\\
Y\\
Z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
60\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The first matrix contains the coefficients of the variables in the system, the second matrix contains the variables themselves. The matrix after the equal sign contains the values of the equations in the system.
This may seem like a weird thing to do, but watch what happens when we multiply the first two matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
560V-560W+0X+0Y+0Z\\
-560V+1526W+0X-910Y+0Z\\
0V+0W+2560X-560Y+0Z\\
0V-910W-560X+2470Y-1000Z\\
0V+0W+0X-1000Y+2120Z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
60\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is basically the system of equations we wanted to solve, but written in terms of matrices.
Working with this system in terms of matrices makes things a bit nicer, because we can solve for the second matrix similar to how we would solve an algebraic equation.
Returning to the first matrix equation, we can multiply both sides (from the left) by the inverse of the first matrix, and express the second matrix in a way that allows us to find the values of the given variables. To save space, I will denote the first matrix as $M$ and its inverse as $M^{-1}$.
$$
\begin{gather*}
M^{-1}\cdot M\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
V\\
W\\
X\\
Y\\
Z
\end{pmatrix}
=M^{-1}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
60\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
V\\
W\\
X\\
Y\\
Z
\end{pmatrix}=
M^{-1}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
60\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
$$
If we multiply $M^{-1}$ and the values matrix, we will get:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
V\\
W\\
X\\
Y\\
Z
\end{pmatrix}\approx
\begin{pmatrix}
0.22153\\
0.11439\\
0.01214\\
0.05549\\
0.02618
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which were the values you provided.
This is probably the closest you can get to solving this system by hand, unless, again, you know how to find the inverse of a $5\times 5$ matrix by hand. If you want to learn more about this method and matrices, I highly recommend you go through chapter $12$ of the book "Mathematics Applications and interpretation HL $2$" by Haese Mathematics (ISBN: $978$-$1$-$925489$-$60$-$6$). It has a very comprehensible and friendly style of writing and lots of solutions.
Hope this helps! :)

Just a small addition to my answer, $M^{-1}\cdot M=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. $I$ multiplied by any matrix is the matrix itself, which is why we were able to express the second matrix in a nice way.

This is a good explanation of how systems of equations are related to matrices, and how the inverse of a matrix can theoretically be used to solve the system. I just wanted to comment that this method works only when the system has a unique solution. And if you were going to find the inverse by hand, you would need to perform row operations, so you might as well just row-reduce the augmented matrix.

Thank you all for your help!
